# How to perform search in two (or more) columns in one table by variable in python/sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Good day all. Lurking here has been a great help - thanks in advance.
What I'd like to do is accept an input from the user, then search both the 'type' and the 'count' columns of the 'mytable' table for anything that matches the user's input.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

var = raw_input("What are you looking for: ")
print "Standby; looking for : ", var
vart = '%'+var+'%'  # to add wildcards to the var string

con = lite.connect('test.db')

print 
print "Ok. Here's what I found."
print

with con:
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable" )
#   cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? )", [vart]) # this actually works - but only searches type column
#   cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? ) OR WHERE count like ( ? )", [vart], [vart] ) fails
#   cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? ) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE count LIKE ( ?)", [vart], [vart])

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    # now row has each line to deal with
    #print len(rows)    #prints the number of lines in the db
    for row in rows:
        #print len(row) # prints the number of items in the list
        # if var in row[0]... then print
        mstr=row[0]
        print mstr.encode('ascii'), row[1]
```

Here is the puny database:

```
type : count
fox|23
dog|34
cat|99
bird|123
rat|201
mouse|23
hedgehog|44
gnu|666
```

I was successful at searching one column only for the input string, but when I try to do both columns at once, it fails. There's got to be a way that using the sqlite3 functions and not rely on the python ones.

Answer (score 0):

A valid un-nested SQL `SELECT` statement only has one `WHERE` statement; also, if you're passing multiple parameters to a sqlite cursor, they must be contained in a *single* list. The correct syntax for your code would be:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? ) OR count like ( ? )', [vart, vart])
```

Comment: When I change the cur.execute line to read:

cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? ) OR count like ( ? )" ,[vart] )
I get the following error:

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
If I then add the second [vart] as such:

cur.execute( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ( ? ) OR count like ( ? )" ,[vart], [vart] )
I then get this error:

TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
Gave a run at both of these types of query's before with similar results.

Comment: The parameters need to be contained in a single list; i've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score -1):

just a little syntax fix, and I spruced up your python to be more pep8 friendly (and closer to python3 support, although raw_input is not native in python3).  From that you should be able to expand....

```
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite
'''
made your code more pep8 python like
note comments in python are reserved for
why not what..e.g. code is self descriptive
of what, but why is what is important
'''

print('{}'.format(sys.argv))  # debug

var = raw_input("What are you looking for: ")
print("Standby; looking for :{}".format(var))
vart = '%{}%'.format(var)

con = lite.connect('test.db')

print("\nOk. Here's what I found.\n")

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ? or count LIKE ?'
    cur.execute(sql_query, ['%{0}%'.format(var), '%{0}%'.format(var)])

    try:
        rows = cur.fetchall()
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    for row in rows:
        mstr = row[0]
        print('Found: {} : {}'.format(mstr.encode('ascii'), row[1]))
```

**output examples**

```
host-wifi:java user$ python /tmp/p.py
['/tmp/p.py']
What are you looking for: 99
Standby; looking for :99

Ok. Here's what I found.

Found: cat : 99
host-wifi:java user$ python /tmp/p.py
['/tmp/p.py']
What are you looking for: 3
Standby; looking for :3

Ok. Here's what I found.

Found: fox : 23
Found: dog : 34
Found: bird : 123
```

Comment: Sweet! Going to have to spend a wee bit of time with your code to understand it. Matter of fact, I just found ( fell into ) another method which is to write :  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE ? or count LIKE ? ",(vart, vart))
which works as well. Many many thanks. Al

Comment: This will blow up when the search string contains single quotes.

Comment: CL yes you need more advanced format syntax to protect quotes.  Good warning.

Comment: cgseller - could you direct me to a discussion on your use of .format() and how to use it correctly? I don't seem to be able to find anything that is appropriate.

Comment: The python docs are good references, .format is a string method.   This PEP document I think does a good job of covering the formatting  :  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: Thanks cgseller! Now for the noob question... what does PEP stand for ?